# Processing Dynamic Form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, server-side-validation

I've a JS dynamic form, where i can add or remove fields:

```
Field 1
Field 2
Field 3
Field 4
```

Now if I remove Field 2 and add a new field:

```
Field 1
Field 3
Field 4
Field 5
```

I'm sending this through Ajax POST inside a form element.
My problem is server side PHP processing. How can I know how many fields I have inside $_POST array and what are their ids? I'm generating unique id using "field" + counterIndex, but following the example how can I be able to understand that I have a total of 4 fields and that number 2 is missing? By the way, inside the form I have static fields too.

Comment: `array_keys` and `count`?

Comment: Maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: @PatrickEvans my thoughts exactly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done through PHP as `$_POST` is itself an array thus it can be looped.

Say, you have fields :

`<input name="dyn[id1]"/>`

`<input name="dyn[id2]"/>`

In the backend PHP file,

Loop through the `$_POST` as following:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT_BTN'])) {
  if (! empty($_POST['dyn'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['dyn'] as $dyn_id => $dyn_val) {
     // "$dyn_id" is your ID you needed.
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Nice. The index is optionnal though : name="dyn[]" and then foreach.