# How to pass multiple input fields having same class and name to ajax request and change corresponding fields based on reply?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have a form like below;

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr><td><input class="asdf" type="text" name="qwerty" value=""/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="items" type="text" name="item" value=""/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="items" type="text" name="item" value=""/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="items" type="text" name="item" value=""/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="items" type="text" name="item" value=""/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="mybutton">clickme</button></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I have some fields with similar name. I want to pass these into my ajax handler in a single instance. Also according to the ajax reply, the corresponding input field's value may be changed to either true or false.

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
  var myitem = $('.items').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajaxhandler.php',
    data: 'qwerty='+$('.asdf').val()+'&item='+myitem,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      if(result == "true"){
        //change each correspinding input field to true
      }else{
        //change each correspinding input field to false
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Also I am little confused how to do the ajax reply. How can I achieve this? Below is an image showing the form before and after ajax (what I am trying to achieve);

[image: Requirement]

The input form fields (items) are generated dynamically. Sometimes there may be 1, sometimes 5 or 10. So it is not possible to give them separate names (like item1, item2 etc) and a common class, and catch them inside php like `$_POST['item1']`, `$_POST['item2']` etc. I want to know how to set the JavaScript as well as the ajax PHP.

Comment: use `serialize()` function to post all form data in ajax request and change `name=item` to `name=item[]`

Comment: Or use `$('.items').serializeArray()` and `json_decode()` in the handler.

Comment: true false means you want to disable and enable?

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133629/processing-dynamic-form/19133722#19133722

Answer (score 4):

Try with this

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr><td><input class="asdf" type="text" name="qwerty" value="0"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="items" type="text" name="item[]" value="1"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="items" type="text" name="item[]" value="2"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="items" type="text" name="item[]" value="3"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="items" type="text" name="item[]" value="4"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="mybutton">clickme</button></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Script

```
$('form').serialize()
```

In your code

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
  var mydata = $('form').serialize()
  // it will return like this qwerty=0&item%5B%5D=1&item%5B%5D=2&item%5B%5D=3&item%5B%5D=4
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajaxhandler.php',
    data: mydata,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      if(result == "true"){
        //change each correspinding input field to true
      }else{
        //change each correspinding input field to false
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: and what about ajaxhandler.php? how can i return corresponding true and false? also i want to set true or false in form fields. For example, if the item1 value found false in php, the form field value may be changed from item1 to false.

Comment: how can i grab each item inside php?